# Confusion in multiple X & Y values for single element on inkscape editor

Tags: c#, svg, inkscape

I am working with an inkscape editor. I have an issue with path element x, y positioning. The path element position is calculated from d attribute m values. I have an image to shows :

[image]

In this image i have a path element selected (*on right side*) and its xml properties are open using xml editor on inkscape (*on left side*). If you see i have highlighted the two **X** values with `red ink`. One value is on inkscape top menu bar and another value is inside the d attribute `(m x, y ..)` on xml editor.

I am confused with these values. Because when i move the path element both values are changing. Can anyone tell me the relation between these values and by which formula i get one X value from another X value.

Answer (score 0):

Inkscapes capabilities of producing clean SVG Code are rather suboptimal.
You probably see absolute and relative values there, where the relative values in the XML Code are probably relative to a `transform="translate(x,y)"` in the node itself or a parent node.

on a side note, i think IE cannot read the transform-attribute. try open it in IE, if its all broken, then its that;-)